# Term not reduced as expected

Tags: agda

The following lemma should be trivial: Combining the plus sign and a natural is the same  that using the plus constructor on this natural.

```
module sign where
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Integer using (_◃_; +_)
open import Data.Sign renaming (+ to s+)
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

lemma : ∀ y  → s+ ◃ y ≡ + y
lemma y = refl
```

But `lemma` fails to typecheck with:

```
s+ ◃ y != + y of type Data.Integer.ℤ
when checking that the expression refl has type s+ ◃ y ≡ + y
```

I'm using `lib-0.7` and according to [this link](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~nad/listings/lib-0.7/Data.Integer.html), `◃` is defined as:

```
_◃_ : Sign → ℕ → ℤ
_      ◃ ℕ.zero  = + ℕ.zero
Sign.+ ◃ n       = + n
Sign.- ◃ ℕ.suc n = -[1+ n ]
```

So I expected that `s+ ◃ y`, following the second pattern rule, evaluate to `+ y` and typechecking to succeed.

What is amiss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the first equation can also be used for `s+ ◃ y`. Only after you know that `y` is not zero, the second equation applies.

The solution is simple:

```
lemma : ∀ y  → s+ ◃ y ≡ + y
lemma zero    = refl
lemma (suc _) = refl
```

Comment: yes, the first rule unifies `y = zero` but `refl`is also valid in this case. What I find weird is that agda doesn't check if `refl` is valid for all unifying pattern rules.

Comment: I know, but this is just how the reduction in Agda works: it won't commit to function equation unless it can show that all the previous ones cannot be (ever) used - and reduction happens only after you select one equation.

Comment: Wouldn't be better to define `_◃_` with just the 2nd and 3d equations?

Comment: That leads to incomplete patterns: `Sign.- ◃ ℕ.zero` is not covered.

Comment: You could reasonably swap the first and second equation to get what you want. However, that would be a tradeoff inasmuch as `sgn ◃ ℕ.zero` would no longer be able to reduce to `+ ℕ.zero` without knowing what `sgn` was.